# Access-control-allow-origin issue with image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, cors

I'm trying to add an image from a different url using a function and im getting an issue with cors saying my request is blocked.

I tried adding a cossOrigin attribute to the image and it still dosnt seem to work

```
function getDataUri(url, callback) {
          var image = new Image();
          image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"

          image.onload = function () {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = this.naturalWidth; // or 'width' if you want a special/scaled size
            canvas.height = this.naturalHeight; // or 'height' if you want a special/scaled size

            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);

            // Get raw image data
            // callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ''));

            // ... or get as Data URI
            callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
          };

          image.src = url;
        }

 getDataUri(imageurl, function (dataURI) {

 })
```

Access to image at 'imageurl' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: The browser is trying to protect you by denying your requesting code, as the response from the URL does not have have the necessary header like the error specifies to say this resource may be used cross origin

Comment: Would the URL need to send that header for it to work? Or is it possible to tell the browser to not care for a certain url?

Comment: The host you are requesting would have to have a CORS policy set up. You can fetch images from the server side first and then provide them to the client to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

I always do: image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');